# Calling 2 classes from Java GUI within Matlab

Tags: java, user-interface, matlab, camera

Since Java cannot unload native libraries when once used (in Matlab; see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096119/matlab-native-library-error)), i am trying to call 2 GUI classes from within Matlab. I am working on grabbing an image from camera and then saving it on disk. I want to use one Java class for communicating with camera while another class (GUI) is still open in Matlab. Is this possible? Here's the code:

1.

```
 public class GUI
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Just open up the window and start things running
    MainWindow mWindow = new MainWindow();
    }

    public static void main2()
    {
        MainWindow.grabImage(0);
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class MainWindow

{

static volatile int commandVal;
        Thread updateThread;
        static CameraImage cImage;
static int fs_c =1;
    MainWindow(){

    JFrame main_f = new JFrame("M");
        main_f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main_f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        main_f.getContentPane().add(tabPane1, "Center");

        main_f.pack();
        main_f.setVisible(true);
                kkk = 1;

        mySerial = new CameraSerial(cWindow.getPort());
}
}
```

3.

```
public static void grabImage(int commandVal){

                   while (MainWindow.kkk == 1) {
                       if (MainWindow.fs_c == 1) {
                        MainWindow.commandVal = 5;
            }
            if (MainWindow.commandVal == 5 || MainWindow.commandVal == 6){

                cImage.sendFrame(0);
                                JFileChooser save_d = new JFileChooser();
                                File saveFile = save_d.getSelectedFile();
                cImage.writeImage(saveFile + ".jpg");

                                MainWindow.fs_c = 0;
                                MainWindow.commandVal = 0;
                                mySerial.write("\r");
                                System.out.println("Camera Ready...");

break;

                        }

                else if (commandVal == -1) {
                MainWindow.commandVal = 0;
                        mySerial.write("\r");
                                status_t.setText("Camera Ready...");
            }
                       else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

}
```

From Matlab I'm calling first `Gui.main([])`, and then `Gui.main2()`. It works for the first time. But when I call `Gui.main2()` again, Matlab does nothing. I think it's a bad code somewhere. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Did you throw that into a debugger and check where it stops?

Comment: Could you reformat the code for readability and add missing parts? For example, where is `MainWindow.fs_c` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an assumption without having more information:

This check:

```
if (MainWindow.fs_c == 1) {
  MainWindow.commandVal = 5;
}
```

And later this (note that `commandVal` would be 5 after the check succeeded for the first time):

```
MainWindow.fs_c = 0;
MainWindow.commandVal = 0;
```

Here's the problem:

In the first run, `commandVal` is set to 5, assuming `MainWindow.fs_c` is initially 1.
Thus `MainWindow.fs_c = 0;` is executed.

In the second run `MainWindow.fs_c == 1` is false (`MainWindow.fs_c` is now 0) and `MainWindow.commandVal` was also set to 0. Thus the method doesn't do anything, except sleeping for 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did the obvious, deleting two confusing lines you suggested, and it worked!!!

Comment: @Makaroni Well, I don't know the logic you're trying to implement. A quick solution would be to omit the `MainWindow.fs_c = 0;` line, but I guess that might break other logic. So unfortunately, I can't give you any other good suggestion than to debug and check the logic you try to implement.